# How to dynamically specify name of column to be changed in r.data table without changing the original object?

Tags: r, data.table

I have R `data.table` object and I would like to print out the data.table with some change to one of the columns (which I specify dynamically).

**Example:**

Let's have a data.table like:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

And I want to increase either column y or v by 1 and see the result without making any change to the actual DT.

If I was fine with changing DT, I could just run:

```
col_to_change = 'y'
DT[, c(col_to_change) := list(get(col_to_change) + 1)]
DT
```

However, I'd rather not make changes to `DT`. I can work around this issue by making a copy of the table and then adjusting the changed object, such as:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT2[, c(col_to_change) := list(get(col_to_change) + 1)]
DT2
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT2[, c(col_to_change) := list(get(col_to_change) + 1)]
DT2
```

I would like to know if there is way to do this without changing the columns by reference.

Ideally I would then bind the original `DT` and the changed `DT` as in:

```
finalDT <- rbindlist(list(DT, DT2))
```

And I would like to be able to do this without making copy of DT first, therefore in the end I would get something like:

```
finalDT <- rbindlist(list(DT, DT[, <<magic goes here>>]))
```

Comment: Maybe DT[,c(.SD, .(NEW=get(col)+1))]

Comment: I would prefer the variable to have the original name

Comment: You mean in the same table you want the old and new columns to be side by side for comparison but the old and new columns to be of the same names?

Comment: Then maybe DT[,c(.SD, setNames(list(get(col)+1), col))]. Not sure if there will be a warning. Not in front of computer to test

Comment: @chinsoon12 it's close but not entirely. It adds an extra column while i'd like to see the same amount of columns with variables in the original order. Therefore, something like `orig_name_order <- names(DT)` and then 
`DT[,c(.SD, setNames(list(get(col_to_change)+1), col_to_change)), .SDcols = !col_to_change][, orig_name_order, with = F]` is actually almost what i need. Just wonder if there is a bit more elegant way

Comment: Anyway, i think the use of setNames basically answers my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Slightly shorter: `DT[, c(.SD, setNames(list(get(col_to_change)+1), col_to_change))[names(DT)], .SDcols = !col_to_change]`